# Calling the Interviewer after the Interview for Feedback

Tags: interviewing

It's been a week after I had an interview with a bank. They told my recruiter that I had done well and it is looking good for me.

However, it's been a week and my recruiter has not been able to reach any of them for feedback and neither have I heard anything, although they did not say to me or my recruiter that I didn't get the job.

My recruiter has placed numerous people with this bank with other managers and never with this one, so my recruiter has no clue what's going on.

I have already sent an email, however I have not gotten a response.

Would it be appropriate for me to call my interviewer and ask for some feedback?

Comment: Wait. Do you want feedback or just a clear communication of whether you are still being considered. The answer depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do remember that employers also have other work to do than filling a particular position.  A week isn't much time, I have seen employers take months to decide on a hire. Further at this time of year, one or more of the hiring officials may be on vacation. So I wouldn't panic.

Now the reality of life is that even if you did well, you may not get the job. Someone else may have done better or they may have decided not to fill the position for financial reasons or any one of a hundred different things. Companies aren't terribly concerned about letting those who didn't get hired know. So you may never hear from many of the jobs you apply for or interview for.  So don't put all your eggs in one basket, keep pursuing other opportunities. If this one is going to happen it will, but in the meantime keep looking, you may find something you like better.

Hiring offficals do like the immediate follow up of a thank you note, but continual contact after that, is annoying and may, in fact, lessen your chances of being hired. If you are the person they are interested in, they won't forget you. Since you are going through a recruiter, let him do the contacting.

Comment: You said some employers won't even tell you if you weren't chosen, but my recruiter has been dealing with them for quite some time. Shouldn't they (courtesy at the very least) tell her that I wasn't chosen?

Comment: Employers are known for courtesy in hiring. And truly after only a week, they may not even be finished interviewing.

Comment: What would you say is the best quality that an interviewee can have, in addition to knowing all his stuff of course, that would make an interviewer say "This is the guy, period."

Comment: There is no right answer to that, the best guy for my job isn't the best guy for the job in the building two doors down. No one is the best guy for every job even in the same field. Part of what they are looking for is how you fit with the other people they already have. Rarely do experienced interviewers decide on someone before they have talked to the other candidates and when they do it is often for political reasons (the person is the CEO's cousin for instance). It would also depend on the level you are hiring for.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I will continue to wait...hopefully I get the job...=)

Answer (score 8):

**No**, it would not be appropriate for you to call the interviewer. The interviewer's responsibility was to meet with you, determine if you are a good fit for the open position, and deliver that evaluation to the hiring manager.  The interviewer is not able to hire you, and has no further responsibility to you.  If you do anything more than sending an E-mail to say "Thank you, I enjoyed meeting you", you will reduce your chance to be hired.  The interviewer will go to the hiring manager and say "I just got a strange call from czchlong wondering whether we were planning to hire him.  I don't know why he called me instead of talking to the recruiter."

Answer (score 0):

**No**. It already sounds like you've done enough follow up on this. Pushing any further will just make you come across as annoying or pushy. It can take up to a month for them to get back to you about a job. They are also busy. Just wait and don't hold your breath. Keep looking for another job. You've done all you can do.

Comment: I would add -- if they do get a job offer at another place, they could use that to get clarification from this one without sounding pushy (and at that point, if it's pushy, so be it). "Hey, I have an offer from place B that I need to act on quickly, but since you're my first choice, just wanted to make sure before moving forward" etc.